# After using InfoPath 2010 to modify a SharePoint 2010 List Form, no edits are saved through the editfs.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I customized a SharePoint list form via InfoPath but no the editfs.aspx that was created does not save any edits. Delete and Create work but the edit form functions as if it saves but it does not. Please help.